# Razor Dropdown onchange event not firing always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using dropdownlist helper in my razor view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", null, "Select Your Country", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "clickMe()" })
```

I have placed my jquery file in the head section of Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

But when I placed my script in a razor view

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function clickMe() { 
            alert();
        }
    });
</script>
```

it gives Reference error : clickMe() is undefined.
When I try this code to popup an alert to check that my jquery file is loaded
this works fine

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `box()` is a function which has nothing to do with the code you have shown - did you mean `clickMe()`? The code you have shown works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I much prefer putting the click events in the script.  Try removing your on change event and replacing your function clickMe with

```
$(document).on('change', '#Country', function(){
    alert('made it!');
});
```

this selects on the ID of the dropdown which I believe will be country in the rendered drop down

Answer (score 4):

The actual reason this doesn't work is because of [Scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Lexical_scoping).  The following code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", 
  null, 
  "Select Your Country", 
  new { @class = "form-control", 
        onchange = "clickMe()" })
```

Yields something like (I hope):

```
<select onchange="clickMe()">
// this is looking for a global `clickMe()` function
// but is it available?
</select>
```

I've annotated your code here:

```
  // clickMe() is out of scope
  // it is not available here

  $(document).ready(function () 
  // start of anonymous function scope
  {

    function clickMe() 
    // start of clickme function scope
    { 
      alert();
    }
    // end of clickme function scope

    // clickMe() is available here
    // it was defined in this scope

  });
  // end of anonymous function scope

  // clickMe() is out of scope
  // it is not available here

</script>
```

I absolutely do not recommend this, but to understand how you *could make it work horribly, you could do the following*:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () 
  {
    window.clickMe = function()
    { 
      alert();
    }
  });
</script>
```

By assigning the function to the window object you make it globally available.

The better way to do it, taking advantage of [Matt Bodily's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888029/209259) might look like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function clickMe() { 
            alert('made it!');
        }

        $(document).on('change', '#Country', clickMe );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
<script>
 $('#CountryID').change(function() {
    var value = $('#CountryID').val();


<script>
```

Just make sure you give your dropdown name= or id=

Comment: You have a typo, an apostrophe is missing after first CountryId.